# jquery disable button AND post

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jquery to disable a submit button to prevent double post.
The problem is that once the buttons is disabled, it doest not POST

i created a jsfiddle to show

http://jsfiddle.net/dg0ejuhq/1/

the code is the following

```
$(function () {
  $("#scr_submit_btn").click(function () {
      $('#scr_submit_btn').submit();
      $("#scr_submit_btn").attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

and the html

```
<form id="form" name="persona" action="publicar.php" method="post">
<!-- inputs and others -->
<button id="scr_submit_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Enviar</button>
</form>
```

i cant figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: what do you mean by double post?

Comment: It submits in JSFiddle (although to nothing, because the resource isn't available for us). You should also switch your disabled line and submit line if you want to do it in that order specifically.

Comment: when a person clicks the submit button more than once and the database records it twice (or more)

Comment: why you using  submit button and  using .click on that..

Comment: Remove `$('#scr_submit_btn').submit();` and try it again.

Comment: Are you trying to make an Ajax form submission? The way it looks to me right now, you will load a new page upon submission and it won't matter about disabling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form has a submit event.. you can use that to disable the button, like this

```
$('#form_newsecret').submit(function () {
   $("#scr_submit_btn").prop("disabled", true);
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function () {
  $("#form").submit(function () {
      $("#scr_submit_btn").prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(function () {
  $("#scr_submit_btn").one("click",function () {
      $('#scr_submit_btn').submit();
  });
});
```